# inline grid vs grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am checking out inline-grid vs. grid and I understand that `inline-grid` doesn't create a block style grid but then what defines the width of it?
In this example: https://yoksel.github.io/grid-cheatsheet/ , `inline-grid` shows the squares at 40px wide but what defines that?  The style has the column at `1fr` but where is it getting the 40px from?

Comment: `min-width: 2.5rem;`

Answer (score 1):

The child elements have the following styles applied to them which causes them to be 40px wide and tall.

```css
.child {
  min-width: 2.5rem;
  min-height: 2.5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```